# How to use two keys as trigger AutoHotKey?

Tags: autohotkey

I would like to use `ctrl + w + x` as a hotkey, but of course `^wx::` is an invalid hotkey.

here the ressources I've found, I tried them but they didn't worked for me, (though english isn't my native language so I may have misreaded??)

the AutoHotKey documentation for the list of keys
https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm

An AutoHotKey topic named "Press 2 buttons at the same time?" from 2018
https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?t=45869

Another Autohotkey topic named "Trying to activate a key press using 2 keys" from 2014
https://autohotkey.com/board/topic/109093-trying-to-activate-a-key-press-using-2-keys-tried-a-bc-error-on-run-help-please-s/

thanks in advance for helping me :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one solution based on the [first example from the Input command in the Documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Input.htm#Examples):

```
delay := 3.0 ;number of seconds to wait for additional input

$^w::
Input, SingleKey, L1T%delay%, {LControl}{RControl}{LAlt}{RAlt}{LShift}{RShift}{LWin}{RWin}{AppsKey}{F1}{F2}{F3}{F4}{F5}{F6}{F7}{F8}{F9}{F10}{F11}{F12}{Left}{Right}{Up}{Down}{Home}{End}{PgUp}{PgDn}{Del}{Ins}{BS}{CapsLock}{NumLock}{PrintScreen}{Pause}
if (SingleKey = "x"){
    ;;;;;;;
    MsgBox Put Hotkey here
    Send ctrl + w + x was pressed
    ;;;;;;;
}
else{
    Send {Ctrl Down}{w}{Ctrl Up}
    Send %SingleKey%
}

return
```

---

### Explanation of Code:

#### Setup:

Declare a variable to hold the amount of time you want the hotkey to wait for an 'x' input after <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is pressed, called `delay`

#### Hotkey Declaration: When <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> is pressed

1. Wait `delay` number of seconds for the user to press another key
2. If that key was <kbd>x</kbd>, then send your custom hotkey
3. Otherwise, send <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>, followed by whatever key was pressed by the user.

---

Other Notes:

1. Using the `$` hotkey modifier to prevent an infinite recursive loop

---

If it doesn't work properly, feel free to let me know and I can try to help you

Comment: Interestingly, the if statement won't be trigered when I press X if the keys ctrl and w are down, the x has to be pressed completely alone